# Krajee-bootstrap file input plugin:: How can i get the total number of the files from 'Drag & drop'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, input, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap - [krajee file input plugin](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input/demo#ajax-uploads). Here i want to get the total number of files are uploaded from the '***drag & drop files here***' field.i included this plugin in a form,so when i click the submit button, it should show the error message if the the file is not uploaded.

```
              $("#file-1").fileinput({
                 uploadUrl: 'file/fileupload.php', 
                 allowedFileExtensions : ['jpg', 'jpeg','png'],
                 overwriteInitial: false,
                 maxFileSize: 1024,
                 maxFilesNum: 10,
             });


             $(".btn-warning").on('click', function()
             {
              if ($('#file-4').attr('disabled'))
              {
                $('#file-4').fileinput('enable');
              } 
              else
              {
                $('#file-4').fileinput('disable');
              }
            });
```

Here is the image before upload  [image]

And this is after upload
[image]

so i need to check whether those images are uploaded or not.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#file-1").fileinput({
                 uploadUrl: 'file/fileupload.php', 
                 allowedFileExtensions : ['jpg', 'jpeg','png'],
                 overwriteInitial: false,
                 maxFileSize: 1024,
                 maxFilesNum: 10,
             }).on('filebatchpreupload', function(event, data) {
    var n = data.files.length, files = n > 1 ? n + ' files' : 'one file';
    if (!window.confirm("Are you sure you want to upload " + files + "?")) {
        return {
            message: "Upload aborted!", // upload error message
            data:{} // any other data to send that can be referred in `filecustomerror`
        };
    }).on('fileuploaded', function(){
            alert("Upload completion message after plugin refresh.");
        });
});
```

Comment: @RenjithVR plz check above code...update. If it does not work, you can remove .on('filebatchpreupload', function(event, data) {
    var n = data.files.length, files = n > 1 ? n + ' files' : 'one file';
    if (!window.confirm("Are you sure you want to upload " + files + "?")) {
        return {
            message: "Upload aborted!", // upload error message
            data:{} // any other data to send that can be referred in `filecustomerror`
        };
    }) and see if other on statement works...ok?